# Can someone explain what /proc/<pid>/sched fields are saying

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

```
picom (1207, #threads: 10)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
se.exec_start                                :      17887655.289274
se.vruntime                                  :        722667.854726
se.sum_exec_runtime                          :        117689.168925
se.nr_migrations                             :                57698
nr_switches                                  :              1263101
nr_voluntary_switches                        :              1242243
nr_involuntary_switches                      :                20858
se.load.weight                               :              1048576
se.avg.load_sum                              :                  129
se.avg.runnable_sum                          :               133034
se.avg.util_sum                              :               120008
se.avg.load_avg                              :                    2
se.avg.runnable_avg                          :                    2
se.avg.util_avg                              :                    2
se.avg.last_update_time                      :       17887263811584
se.avg.util_est.ewma                         :                    9
se.avg.util_est.enqueued                     :                    9
uclamp.min                                   :                    0
uclamp.max                                   :                 1024
effective uclamp.min                         :                    0
effective uclamp.max                         :                 1024
policy                                       :                    0
prio                                         :                  120
clock-delta                                  :                   15
mm->numa_scan_seq                            :                    0
numa_pages_migrated                          :                    0
numa_preferred_nid                           :                   -1
total_numa_faults                            :                    0
current_node=0, numa_group_id=0
numa_faults node=0 task_private=0 task_shared=0 group_private=0 group_shared=0
```

I'm all reading all files and folder from /proc and almost got everything on internet, but I'm not satisfied with 'sched' info, as some places its incomplete other don't satisfied my need.

As I'm building low level application and want to juice out /proc.